# concatenate list and object then use enumerable c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model class that stores information in the datatbase. then I created a list test. This lists get xml data and puts its in a list.

so in my controller,

I have this linq query:

```
function somefunction()
{
    var mov = from m in db.Movies
                          select m;
    List<Movie> items = MyXMLExtract();//this gets xml file from a url, then returns a list<Movie>.
    var thistest = mov.ToList().Concat(items);; //I concatenate the two linq

    return thistest;
}
```

in my view I have this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Movie>
```

however, everything in this view gives an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Movie'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I understand the error, but how to deal with it?
Basically I am returning a list, and I am using `Ienumerable`, what to do?
my view is just a `foreach` loop output the fields names.

both movie and items use the same db model from Movies.

this below gives me an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    thistest = thistest.Where(s => s.description.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.title.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.location.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: What does the error _say_?

Comment: Where does `mov` get used, and where does `cal` come from?

Comment: please see my edits and updates based on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ tries to pass List items to DB and concat them on SQL Server side.

change mov.Concat(items); to mov.ToList().Concat(items) to pull data from SQL before concatenation.

Comment: ...or don't allocate any superfluous storage by using `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`

Comment: could you please post a complete source code for that error? it looks like description, title or location was deserialized as null. Try changing you code to something like '(s.description != null && s.description.Contains(searchString))'

Comment: you are correct, now i need to fix my output but all works perfectly now.